# How do i make a if statement that deny a username longer then 10 characters

Tags: php, if-statement

Im creating a register and login system but i need to know how i make a if statement that first counts the characters and see if it is longer then XX values.

I've tried a lot of stuff but i could'nt find it out. I've seen some youtube tutorials but none of them really answers this question..

The one that i though would work was this:

```
if( $username > 30 === true ) { ... }
```

But it didn't work, so now i have no idea how i should do this, i need help...

EDIT:
Thanks for all the answers! Now since i got help i know what i need to do! here is how the problem was fixed:

```
if( strlen($username) > 30 === true )
```

Comment: `if (strlen($username) > 30) { // Longer than 30 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use PHP strlen to count the number of digits in your variable.

For example:

```
if( strlen($username) > 30 ) { ... }
```

Comment: No need to check if it's true or not, the `strlen` returns an integer.

Comment: This worked, thank you for answering my question this fast!